# Patches are not applying after saving in X64dbg

Tags: x64dbg

I'm new to this and I used X64 debugger for a short while

The thing is , I was testing the security for some software (for educational purposes only!) and finally I found a way break into it , but when I save the work and changes don't apply !

The part where the arrow points in the image never change form `je` to `jne`:
[image]

Any idea why ?

Comment: I noticed that the program was packed with UPX , after unpacking it all went fine .